# Check For Active Internet Connection (Mac App)

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have seen lots of tutorials on how to check for internet connection on iOS, but I am finding it very hard to do this on OSX. What I have so far is this whenever it tries to load a website and there is no internet (and when the app launches):

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
if (data)
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
else
    NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
    [RetryInternetWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
```

---

The only problem I have found is that it seems to think that I never have any internet connection and displays the window that I told it to. Is there a simple way to check for internet on a mac app?

Comment: dont try to download some dummy data to detect if you have network. you should use the APIs provided for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Reachability API for this.  See this [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_ReachConnect/SC_ReachConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH204-BHAFBAHI).

There is also a drop-in replacement on [github](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).

Comment: +1 for drop-in replacement -- looks way nicer than the default API

Comment: @Daij-Djan I can't vouch for it though; I've never used it myself.